# What are the differences between this and this() in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Please confirm me is `this` keyword refer to its owning class and `this()` method refers to its owning class constructors.

```java
class Tester {

    private String blogName;

    public Tester() {
        this("stackoverflow");
    }

    public Tester(String str) {
        this.blogName = str;
    }

    public String getBlogName() {
        return blogName;
    }
}
```

It help me to if there are other differences between these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example calls the overloaded constructor in the default constructor.  You can call all overloaded constructors this way.  It has to be the first line in the constructor, just like calls to super().

The second one shows how the special name `this` refers to the current instance within the class.  It's only required to sort out name duplication:

```
public class ThisDemo {

    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "REQUIRED"; 
    private String value;

    public ThisDemo() {
        this(DEFAULT_VALUE);
    }

    publi ThisDemo(String value) {
        // Required here because the private member and parameter have same name
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() { 
        // Not required here, but I prefer to add it.  
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the object on which behalf the current method was invoked. `this(anything)` is an invocation of constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`this("stackoverflow");` is calling the other constructor in the class (this is called a delegated constructor).

`this.blogName= str1;` is assigning a reference to whatever `str1` is referring to to the *field* `blogName`. The `this` in this instance is redundant but is used to disambiguate a field name to an identically named function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a keyword in Java, it means its current instance of the class.

`this("stackoverflow")` is calling constructor in the class which will be a overloaded call. You can call any other constructors of the same class this way.